# PHP undefined index / variable

Tags: php, mysql, forms, indexing, undefined

I get the following error with the below code:

> Notice: Undefined variable: error in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\projects\Learning\php\Databases\Forms and
>   Databases\project.php on line 35

The code:

```
<?php 
    $clicked = false;
    if($clicked == false && isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if ($_POST['label'] == '') {
            echo "<p>You must enter in a label!</p>";   
            $error = true;
        }
        if ($_POST['url'] == '') {
            echo "<p>You must enter in a url!</p>"; 
            $error = true;
        }
        if ($_POST['status'] == '') {
            echo "<p>You must enter in a status (0 or 1)!</p>"; 
            $error = true;  
        }
    }       
    if ($error != true) {
        if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == '1'  ) {
            $query = "INSERT INTO nav (label, url, target, status, position) VALUES  ('$_POST[label]', '$_POST[url]', '$_POST[target]', $_POST[status], $_POST[position])"; 
            $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
            if ($result) {
                echo "<p>You've added a new navigation link!</p>";
            }
            else {
                echo "<p>An error has occured!</p>"; 
                echo mysqli_error($dbc);
                echo '<p>'.$query.'</p>';
            }
            $clicked = true;//submit button replaced        
        }
    }           
?>          

<h1>Navigation</h1> 
<h5>*Required Fields</h5>
<form action="project.php" method="post">
    <label>*Label:</label>
    <p><input type="text" name="label" size="50" placeholder="Enter a Label" value=""/></p>         
    <label>Position:</label>
    <p><input type="text" name="position" size="10" placeholder="Enter a Position" value=""/></p>           
    <label>*URL:</label>
    <p><input type="text" name="url" size="50" placeholder="Enter a URL" value=""/></p>     
    <label>Target:</label>
    <p><input type="text" name="target" size="50" placeholder="Enter a target" value=""/></p>           
    <label>*Status:</label>
    <p><input type="text" name="status" size="10" value="" /></p>           

<?php 
    if ($clicked == false) {
        echo '<p><button type="submit" name="submit" value = "1" >Add Navigation Link</button></p>';
    }
    else {
        echo '<p><a href "project.php"  id = resetBtn>Do Another</a></p>';
    }   
?>
```

When I make the following changes:

```
if($clicked == false && $_POST['submit'] == "1") {
    if ($_POST['label'] == '') {
        echo "<p>You must enter in a label!</p>";   
        $error = true;
    }
    if ($_POST['url'] == '') {
        echo "<p>You must enter in a url!</p>"; 
        $error = true;
    }
    if ($_POST['status'] == '') {
        echo "<p>You must enter in a status (0 or 1)!</p>"; 
        $error = true;  
    }
}
```

I get these errors:

> Notice: Undefined index: submit in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\projects\Learning\php\Databases\Forms and
>   Databases\project.php on line 18

&

> Notice: Undefined variable: error in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\projects\Learning\php\Databases\Forms and
>   Databases\project.php on line 35

So clearly the button of name "submit" isn't being "seen" for whatever reason; I believe.  This makes some sense to me, kind of... If I'm not mistaken: php reads from start to finish in a linear sort of way, and since the form is below the if statement, the index does not exist yet.  This I think is further corroborated by the fact that once I click the submit button, all errors disappear, and the if statement's error (echo) statements within the if statement, are thus executed.

This is mind boggling. This doesn't work either...

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == '1') {
    if (isset($_POST['label']) && $_POST['label'] == '') {
        echo "<p>You must enter in a label!</p>";   
        $error = true;
    }
    if (isset($_POST['url']) && $_POST['url'] == '') {
        echo "<p>You must enter in a url!</p>"; 
        $error = true;
    }
    if (isset($_POST['status']) && $_POST['status'] == '') {
        echo "<p>You must enter in a status (0 or 1)!</p>"; 
        $error = true;  
    }
}
```

...YET, in a previous version of the code, the combo of isset and "is equal to" for an if-statement's conditions, solved the Unidentified index problem, as it pertained to the $_POST['submit'], here's that code:
ps: as it pertains to this particular block of code, The fellow in the following linked [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s1aq3akyusU&list=PLAkMqlQoeMegZqQs2cApDtU-rb9i2KNkq&index=6), which I'm following along with, does not have any of these errors arise, despite me doing the exact same thing as him.

```
<?php 
    $clicked = false;
    if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == '1'  ) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO nav (label, url, target, status, position) VALUES ('$_POST[label]', '$_POST[url]', '$_POST[target]', $_POST[status], $_POST[position])";  
        $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
        if ($result) {
            echo "<p>You've added a new navigation link!</p>";}
        else {
            echo "<p>An error has occured!</p>"; 
            echo mysqli_error($dbc);
            echo '<p>'.$query.'</p>';
        }       
        $clicked = true;//submit button replaced        
    }   
?>          

<h1>Navigation</h1> 
<h5>*Required Fields</h5>   
<form action="project2.php" method="post">
    <label>*Label:</label>
    <p><input type="text" name="label" size="50" placeholder="Enter a Label" value=""/></p>
    <label>Position:</label>
    <p><input type="text" name="position" size="10" placeholder="Enter a Position" value=""/></p>
    <label>*URL:</label>
    <p><input type="text" name="url" size="50" placeholder="Enter a URL" value=""/></p>
    <label>Target:</label>
    <p><input type="text" name="target" size="50" placeholder="Enter a target" value=""/></p>
    <label>*Status:</label>
    <p><input type="text" name="status" size="10" value="" /></p>

<?php 
    if ($clicked == false) {
        echo '<p><button type="submit" name="submit" value = "1" >Add Navigation Link</button></p>';
    }
    else {
        echo '<p><a href "project2.php"  id = resetBtn>Do Another</a></p>';
    }   
?>
```

again, this works just fine, no errors. So why do I get the undefine variable error in the first block of code I posted? The undefined variable is coming as a result of the subsequent if-statements failing to be executed, and that is I'm assuming a problem to do with the index issue, yet, the errors do not reflect that!

When I replace the conditions with just $clicked == false, as follows:

```
$clicked = false;
if($clicked == false) {
    if ($_POST['label'] == '') {
        echo "<p>You must enter in a label!</p>";   
         $error = true;
    }
    if ($_POST['url'] == '') {
        echo "<p>You must enter in a url!</p>"; 
        $error = true;
    }
    if ($_POST['status'] == '') {
        echo "<p>You must enter in a status (0 or 1)!</p>"; 
        $error = true;  
    }
}
```

I get these three undefined index errors ALONG WITH THE BLOODY CODE which obviuosly executes successfully, despite the three indexes being supposed undefined:

Notice: Undefined index: label in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\projects\Learning\php\Databases\Forms and Databases\project4.php on line 20
You must enter in a label!

Notice: Undefined index: url in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\projects\Learning\php\Databases\Forms and Databases\project4.php on line 24
You must enter in a url!

Notice: Undefined index: status in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\projects\Learning\php\Databases\Forms and Databases\project4.php on line 28
You must enter in a status (0 or 1)!

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). If this is on the public internet you are at **SEVERE** risk.

Comment: @tadman Never seen this notice previously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define $error variable before first IF statement

```
$error = true;
```

because PHP processor doesn't know anything about it

Also in the code nothing about defined database connection, you need to have defined $dbc variable

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  How do I give you commendation? I clicked the checkmark, hopefully that did it.  I'm a noob, but damn, I can't believe even I missed that LOL.  As for the dbc, thank you, i know.

Answer (score 0):

There is alot of exampled code, which I haven't looked all the way through, but.. Long story short, an explanation of your errors are as followed:

> Notice: Undefined variable

Your variable is unintialized when you're trying to access/use it.

```
echo $_HaveNotSetThisVar; // as this is not set prior to using. You're getting an error
```

and

> Notice: Undefined index:

Much like your previous error. This time in an array form:

```
echo $Array['NonExistantKey']; // Undefined index
```

A solution to this would be wrapping variables which might not always be set **and** a form or error handling:

http://php.net/isset

---

Practical usage:

```
if (isset($_HaveNotSetThisVar)){
  echo "Variable Set";
}
```

and the same  for arrays:

```
if (isset($Array['NonExistantKey'])){
   echo "Array Key Set";
}
```

This is the basic of error handling, but can be stacked with other functions for more in-depth handling.

**P.S**

Another thing to ensure, is that you are using the correct variable names, undefined indexes/variables can also be caused by typos:

```
 $Vaar = "Test";
 echo $Var; // Undefined Error
```

Comment: @theconfusedbroom  Well, it's *your* code, what have you changed?